# Find duplicated Rows based on selected columns condition in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an extensive base converted into a dataframe where it is difficult to manually identify the following

The dataframe has columns with the names `from_bus` and `to_bus`, which are unique identifiers regardless of the order, for example for element `0`:

`L_ABAN_MACA_0_1` the associated ordered pair `(109,140)` is the same as `(140,109)`.

|  | name | from_bus | to_bus | x_ohm_per_km |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | L_ABAN_MACA_0_1 | 109 | 140 | 0.444450 |
| 1 | L_AGOY_BAÑO_1_1 | 69 | 66 | 0.476683 |
| 2 | L_AGOY_BAÑO_1_2 | 69 | 66 | 0.476683 |
| 3 | L_ALAN_INGA_1_1 | 189 | 188 | 0.452790 |
| 4 | L_ALAN_INGA_1_2 | 188 | 189 | 0.500450 |

So I want to identify the duplicate ordered pairs and replace them with a single one, whose column value x_ohn_per_km is defined as the sum of the duplicated values, as follows:

|  | name | from_bus | to_bus | x_ohm_per_km |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | L_ABAN_MACA_0_1 | 109 | 140 | 0.444450 |
| 1 | L_AGOY_BAÑO_1_1 | 69 | 66 | 0.953366 |
| 3 | L_ALAN_INGA_1_1 | 189 | 188 | 0.953240 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `groupby` on  `from_bus` and `to_bus` after sorting the values in these columns along `axis=1` then `agg` to aggregate the result, optionally `reindex` to conform the order of columns:

```
c = ['from_bus', 'to_bus']
df[c] = np.sort(df[c], axis=1)

df.groupby(c, sort=False, as_index=False)\
  .agg({'name': 'first', 'x_ohm_per_km': 'sum'})\
  .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Alternative approach:

```
d = {**dict.fromkeys(df, 'first'), 'x_ohm_per_km': 'sum'}
df.groupby([*np.sort(df[c], axis=1).T], sort=False, as_index=False).agg(d)
```

---

```
              name  from_bus  to_bus  x_ohm_per_km
0  L_ABAN_MACA_0_1       109     140      0.444450
1  L_AGOY_BAÑO_1_1        66      69      0.953366
2  L_ALAN_INGA_1_1       188     189      0.953240
```

Comment: Thank you @Shubham Sharma.
One more question, if you want to perform another operation with the repeated rows other than the sum, for example: (0.476683 * 0.476683) / (0.476683 + 0.476683) = 0.2383415

Comment: In that case we can define a custom aggregation function for example in place of `'sum'` we could use `lambda s: s.prod() / s.sum()`

Comment: For the second approach would be?
`d = {**dict.fromkeys(df, 'first'), 'x_ohm_per_km': 'lambda s: s.prod() / s.sum()'}`
`df.groupby([*np.sort(df[c], axis=1).T], sort=False, as_index=False).agg(d)`
doing this also operates on non-duplicated rows

Comment: Remove the quotation marks around lambda..check `d = {**dict.fromkeys(df, 'first'), 'x_ohm_per_km': lambda s: s.prod() / s.sum()}`

Comment: Yes, it was just a typographical error, however, as I mentioned with this function, it operates on non-duplicated rows. How could it be solved. Thank you so much